# Screen CLI prints garbage while PuTTY prints correct chars

Tags: putty, usart

I am working on STM32 Microcontroller. I enabled USART2 and managed to send messages from the STM to my PC. However, even though USART_BaudRate is set to 9600 on the STM, to be able to see the sent messages on my PC I need to set PuTTY's baudrate to 14400. I only figured it out after using oscilloscope.

Right now I am trying to see the same messages using my virtual box that has Linux on it. I made sure that I disconnected my device from Windows OS and connected it to Virtual box. I ran the following command and it showed me absolute garbage. How come the same baudrate that works on PuTTY does not work on the screen CLI? I also tried minicom but it shows the same garbage on my Virtual box. I have tried the main baudrates linked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120992/why-does-cat-ttyusb0-not-produce-output) but all of them show garbage. Can anyone please explain to me the reason behind these shenanigans?

```
$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB1 14400
```

**EDIT**: I downloaded PuTTY on Linux. It also shows me garbage even though I use the same configuration as in the PuTTY on Windows.

Comment: You may want to post the message you're sending and the bytes you receive in binary. The bit patterns often give a clue on what USART parameter is off (bit rate, parity, bits per symbol).

Comment: Maybe first double check your clock rates. If the actual USART's clock is not what you think it is, the bit rate may be off.

Comment: "Can anyone please explain to me the reason behind these shenanigans?" - Unlikely without knowing anything about your µC. What type? How is the device configured (HAL?)? Clocks,...? What's your clock source?

Comment: @JimmyB How come PuTTy on Windows and Linux show me different results?

Comment: How come you send at 9600 and receive at 14400 bps?

Comment: Something's off by some amount and this could cause things to work weird in some cases and not work in others.

Comment: Thats because after looking through oscilloscope, it showed that the baudrate is 14400 when in software it is set to USART_InitStruct.USART_BaudRate = 9600;

Comment: Also note that there's more parameters to a UART comm than baudrate. Some you can configure from userland, some probably not (handling of framing errors...).